# How to print out a pointf in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, draw

I am new to programming and I want to print a dot in the windows form application.
What is the code if I already have a PointF that is assigned with the x & y?
Thank you very much

Comment: You want to print a dot on **what**? your form, your control, or anything else?

Comment: have you tried something? see this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9cadd73f-cfcf-4042-a11b-68ca7b5b66e1/how-to-draw-a-point-on-panel

Comment: Totally unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to print a dot on my form
i got my coordinations for where I want my dot but what Is the code for printing it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `FillRectangle` of a `Graphics` object to fill the rectangle with dimension of `1x1` (looks like a point), because the `Graphics` object doesn't have any method like `SetPixel`:

```
public void SetPixel(PointF p, Color c, Graphics g){
  using(Brush brush = new SolidBrush(c)){
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new RectangleF(p, new Size(1, 1)));
  }
}
//Paint event handler of your form
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
   SetPixel(yourPoint, Color.Red, e.Graphics);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isaac, not a very detailed question, but from what I got is that you have a windows form that you want to draw a "POINT" (1px X 1px dot)? Well its pretty easy if you are using windows forms.

1. to go the designer view of your form
2. right click on the background of the form while the form is selected
   [image]
3. click properties
4. click on the events tab (the lightning bolt) of the properties tab
   [image]
5. scroll down until you see paint event for that form
6. type in a function name for that event
7. browse to your source file for your form
8. using code from below. There are a couple ways to draw a point I use either a 1px line or a filled 1px box

   ```
   private void paintEvent(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       // Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
       Graphics g = e.Graphics;

       // Draw a line in the PictureBox.
       g.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, 50, 50,
           51, 51);
       g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, 50, 50, 1, 1);

   }
   ```

Comment: what is the 50,50,51,51 and what is the g in the beginning?

Comment: it is a var that is passed in view the paintevent "PaintEventArgs e"

Comment: and the 50,50,51,51 is making a line at x = 50 y = 50 to x2 = 51 y2 = 51

Comment: i would use g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, 50, 50, 1, 1); tho it is a one pixel box, there is really no need to fill the box because it is only one pixel in size